# How to write a stored procedure in MySQL that displays two messages when called

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The goal here is to write a script attempts to insert a new category into categories table and if the insert was successful the message:

> 1 row was inserted

If the update is unsuccessful, the procedure should display this message:

> Row was not inserted - duplicate entry

Whenever I run this script, I keep getting the second message no matter how many times I run it, when really it should display the first message, followed by the second. Here is my script. Can someone please help me spot what I'm overlooking? Thank you.

```
    use my_guitar_shop;
   /*drop procedure if exists add_category;*/
   DELIMITER //
  CREATE PROCEDURE add_category(

   in categories VARCHAR(100)

  )
   begin
   declare duplicate_entry_for_key TinyINT DEFAULT FALSE;
   declare continue handler for 1062
   SET duplicate_entry_for_key = TRUE;

  insert into categories values (5, 'Electric');

   select '1 row was inserted.' as message;

   if duplicate_entry_for_key = true then
   select 'Row was not inserted - duplicate entry.' as message;
   end if;
   end //
   DELIMITER ;

   /* call the stored procedure with 'Gibson' */
   call add_category('Gibson');
   call add_category('Gibson');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `duplicate_entry_for_key` to True. If data insert is successful.

Do something like below after insert operation.

```
SET duplicate_entry_for_key = last_insert_id();
```

**OR** *see the below example for bit check.*

**For example:**

```
START TRANSACTION; -- Begin a transaction
INSERT INTO categories
    VALUES
      (
        5
       ,'Electric'
      );
IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN -- ROW_COUNT() returns the number of rows updated/inserted/deleted
     SET duplicate_entry_for_key = TRUE;
     COMMIT; -- Finalize the transaction
ELSE
    SET duplicate_entry_for_key = False;
    --You can ROLLBACK the transaction also - Revert all changes made before the transaction began
 END IF
```